# react-native How to listen to updated mobx state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx

In my react native project, when I click a button, my mobx app state gets updated.

I want to use react `lifecycle method` to listen to this update and automatically update it. So I am using `componentDidUpdate`.

```
  componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    this.setState({number:store.requestObject.number},
    console.log(this.state.number), 'state changed')
  }
```

But it seems like this method will not automatically update.

Should I be using other lifecycle method? Any comments or advise would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

**Edited**

In my first screen, I have a button and `onPress` I can store data to `mobx` `store`. Then, in my second screen, I want to call the `mobx` `state` and update it with my current component's state. I could use button something like:

```
 <Button onPress={()=> this.setState({currentState:store.mobxState})}>
```

Then, my current `component state` will match the `mobx state` it works fine but I want to do it automatically(not with a button).

Comment: You can use setState callback function to get updated state value. And whenever you update your state you can always get it in your render method.

Comment: @VikramThakur thanks for the comment. It would be really nice if you could provide some sample code!

Comment: Sure. I have posted an answer you can try that.

Comment: What is `store.requestObject.number` in your example? Where does it come from? As is, if `componentDidUpdate` is called for any reason, then it'll get stuck in an infinite loop unless `store` or `requestObject` are undefined and an error is thrown.  Can you provide a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces what you're trying to do?

Comment: oh that is my mobx store. I am trying to update my mobx state with the local state.

Comment: Ok, there are two things here then, your mobx app state, and this current component's state.  Which "state" is getting updated?  and which "state" are you trying to update based on the the previous update?  React lifecycle functions typically only care about react state and props (`this.state` and `this.props`).

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with mobx, but have experience with redux.  Brief research shows that mobx appears to also map the store, or store accessors/mutators to react props that get passed around.  Can you provide the button click handler (i.e. the code that does some state (still don't know which one) update), and maybe more of the react component code?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for the comments I really appreciate it! Once I save my mobx state, I want my current component's state to match my mobx state. I hope you get what I am trying to say! Please let me know if you need more detail!

Comment: Well, assuming the button click handler is calling some function to set some value in your mobx state, put the react `setState` call there as well with the same value.  I'm curious now though, why do you want to duplicate app state into a component's state?  Seems like a recipe for bugs.  The component state should be for things **ONLY** the component cares about, i.e. it needs to do some internal tracking, not any whole app concerns.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks I edited my code please take a look! btw the reason I am duplicating is because I am using multiple screen and I want to pass it using mobx.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get changed state value in the next line. We can use the callback method here

```
handleMonthChange_next = () => {
this.setState({
    currentMonth: this.state.currentMonth + 1
}, () => {
 this.props.getCalendarData(this.state.currentMonth)
})}
```

Comment: thanks but I am not sure if we are on the same page. what I am trying to do is listen to the update state and automatically update using the react lifecycle method.

Comment: render method of react is only lifecycle method which gets called after setState in the same class. What is the use case of listing state change in the same class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){

}
```

> Note that this method is fired on every render, regardless of the
>   cause. This is in contrast to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps, which
>   only fires when the parent causes a re-render and not as a result of a
>   local setState.

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

To be more specific, when you call `this.setState({})`, your `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be called and from there you can read your changed state value and perform some operations.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I never seen this method before. I read the documents but still confusing.  `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    this.setState({number:store.requestObject.number},
       console.log(this.state.number), 'state changed')` would not work.
  }

Comment: It would not work like that, it's purpose is to give you an event whenever there is any change in state or props, so whenever you do setState() or your props gets changed, this method will be called.

Comment: Could you please provide a example code I would really appreciate it!

Comment: refer [this](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to user given methods then make your custom event that listen to state

```
stateListiner = (state) =>{
  this.setState(state,()=>{
    //listen to state change after setting it 
    // add your logic after state update 
  })
}

// call the state 
let givenState = {name:'xyz',visible:false,}
this.stateListiner(givenState) // this will set your state and fire the callback function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the react [`setState` callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  this.setState(
    { number: store.requestObject.number },
    () => console.log(this.state.number, 'state changed') // callback will fire after state update
  );
}
```

Note though that setting state within `componentDidUpdate` is recommended to be behind a conditional check so to not get your code into an infinite loop.  The code above will.  Also, the parameters it receives are the previous state and props, not the next.  It's only called after state has been updated or the component receives new prop values.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
    // handle change, log it, api call, call other callback, etc...
  }
}
```